# Trying to install firestore v.9 but credentials won't import

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, service-accounts

This part

```
const serviceAccount = require('./firestore-reactdb-027d52fa212f.json');
```

Results in an error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './firestore-reactdb-027d52fa212f.json' in (...)
```

I downloaded the json file from IAM & admin > Service accounts in the Cloud Platform Console (as instructed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#node.js_2) under "initialize on your own server"). I tried also to download the credentials from the console in firebase (project settings -> service account -> generate new private key).

PS: it's in a react app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those credentials are needed when you make your own service. React app is not a service read about what service is. If you want to use firebase in react app you don't need those secrets. You need firebase config object and you no need to wory about to sharing it. This config object is necesery for firebase to know where he can send requests etc.

**Example object with configurations for firebase.**

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "..."
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was also in the code. I had some firebase-admin import from the google firestore documentation. I fixed it by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yNyiW_41H8&ab_channel=TheNetNinja

Comment: @ObaApi Yeah firebase-admin SDK runs on services or firebase functions (nodejs enviroment) it need this secrets/credentials to be able to connect to database with admin priviliges. You need to install firebase no firebase-admin.

Comment: @ObaApi If my answer is correct please check mark near my answer under votes it looks like a bird.